# App Engine key strategy failing

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I used the following POJO to create an App Engine Endpoint.

```
package com.incident.incidentreporter;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.jdo.annotations.IdGeneratorStrategy;
import javax.jdo.annotations.Persistent;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PrimaryKey;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Blob;

@Entity
public class Incidents {
@Id
@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
@Persistent
private Date incidentdate;
@Persistent
private String incidentdetails;
@Persistent
private double lat;
@Persistent
private double lngtitude;
@Persistent
private String reporter;
@Persistent
private Blob incidentimage;
    public Incidents() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public Incidents(Long id, Date incidentdate, String incidentdetails,
            double lat, double lngtitude, String reporter, Blob incidentimage) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.incidentdate = incidentdate;
        this.incidentdetails = incidentdetails;
        this.lat = lat;
        this.lngtitude = lngtitude;
        this.reporter = reporter;
        this.incidentimage = incidentimage;
    }
    /**
     * @return the incidentdate
     */
    public Date getIncidentdate() {
        return incidentdate;
    }
    /**
     * @param incidentdate the incidentdate to set
     */
    public void setIncidentdate(Date incidentdate) {
        this.incidentdate = incidentdate;
    }
    /**
     * @return the incidentdetails
     */
    public String getIncidentdetails() {
        return incidentdetails;
    }
    /**
     * @param incidentdetails the incidentdetails to set
     */
    public void setIncidentdetails(String incidentdetails) {
        this.incidentdetails = incidentdetails;
    }
    /**
     * @return the lat
     */
    public double getLat() {
        return lat;
    }
    /**
     * @param lat the lat to set
     */
    public void setLat(double lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }
    /**
     * @return the lngtitude
     */
    public double getLngtitude() {
        return lngtitude;
    }
    /**
     * @param lngtitude the lngtitude to set
     */
    public void setLngtitude(double lngtitude) {
        this.lngtitude = lngtitude;
    }
    /**
     * @return the reporter
     */
    public String getReporter() {
        return reporter;
    }
    /**
     * @param reporter the reporter to set
     */
    public void setReporter(String reporter) {
        this.reporter = reporter;
    }
    /**
     * @return the incidentimage
     */
    public Blob getIncidentimage() {
        return incidentimage;
    }
    /**
     * @param incidentimage the incidentimage to set
     */
    public void setIncidentimage(Blob incidentimage) {
        this.incidentimage = incidentimage;
    }
    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }



}
```

The auto generated endpoint code is as below.

```
package com.incident.incidentreporter;

import com.incident.incidentreporter.EMF;

import com.google.api.server.spi.config.Api;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiMethod;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiNamespace;
import com.google.api.server.spi.response.CollectionResponse;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Cursor;
import com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.JPACursorHelper;

import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.Nullable;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.persistence.EntityExistsException;
import javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.Query;

@Api(name = "incidentsendpoint", namespace = @ApiNamespace(ownerDomain = "incident.com", ownerName = "incident.com", packagePath = "incidentreporter"))
public class IncidentsEndpoint {

    /**
     * This method lists all the entities inserted in datastore.
     * It uses HTTP GET method and paging support.
     *
     * @return A CollectionResponse class containing the list of all entities
     * persisted and a cursor to the next page.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "unused" })
    @ApiMethod(name = "listIncidents")
    public CollectionResponse<Incidents> listIncidents(
            @Nullable @Named("cursor") String cursorString,
            @Nullable @Named("limit") Integer limit) {

        EntityManager mgr = null;
        Cursor cursor = null;
        List<Incidents> execute = null;

        try {
            mgr = getEntityManager();
            Query query = mgr.createQuery("select from Incidents as Incidents");
            if (cursorString != null && cursorString != "") {
                cursor = Cursor.fromWebSafeString(cursorString);
                query.setHint(JPACursorHelper.CURSOR_HINT, cursor);
            }

            if (limit != null) {
                query.setFirstResult(0);
                query.setMaxResults(limit);
            }

            execute = (List<Incidents>) query.getResultList();
            cursor = JPACursorHelper.getCursor(execute);
            if (cursor != null)
                cursorString = cursor.toWebSafeString();

            // Tight loop for fetching all entities from datastore and accomodate
            // for lazy fetch.
            for (Incidents obj : execute)
                ;
        } finally {
            mgr.close();
        }

        return CollectionResponse.<Incidents> builder().setItems(execute)
                .setNextPageToken(cursorString).build();
    }

    /**
     * This method gets the entity having primary key id. It uses HTTP GET method.
     *
     * @param id the primary key of the java bean.
     * @return The entity with primary key id.
     */
    @ApiMethod(name = "getIncidents")
    public Incidents getIncidents(@Named("id") Long id) {
        EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
        Incidents incidents = null;
        try {
            incidents = mgr.find(Incidents.class, id);
        } finally {
            mgr.close();
        }
        return incidents;
    }

    /**
     * This inserts a new entity into App Engine datastore. If the entity already
     * exists in the datastore, an exception is thrown.
     * It uses HTTP POST method.
     *
     * @param incidents the entity to be inserted.
     * @return The inserted entity.
     */
    @ApiMethod(name = "insertIncidents")
    public Incidents insertIncidents(Incidents incidents) {
        EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
        try {

            mgr.persist(incidents);
        } finally {
            mgr.close();
        }
        return incidents;
    }

    /**
     * This method is used for updating an existing entity. If the entity does not
     * exist in the datastore, an exception is thrown.
     * It uses HTTP PUT method.
     *
     * @param incidents the entity to be updated.
     * @return The updated entity.
     */
    @ApiMethod(name = "updateIncidents")
    public Incidents updateIncidents(Incidents incidents) {
        EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
        try {
            if (!containsIncidents(incidents)) {
                throw new EntityNotFoundException("Object does not exist");
            }
            mgr.persist(incidents);
        } finally {
            mgr.close();
        }
        return incidents;
    }

    /**
     * This method removes the entity with primary key id.
     * It uses HTTP DELETE method.
     *
     * @param id the primary key of the entity to be deleted.
     */
    @ApiMethod(name = "removeIncidents")
    public void removeIncidents(@Named("id") Long id) {
        EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
        try {
            Incidents incidents = mgr.find(Incidents.class, id);
            mgr.remove(incidents);
        } finally {
            mgr.close();
        }
    }

    private boolean containsIncidents(Incidents incidents) {
        EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
        boolean contains = true;
        try {
            Incidents item = mgr.find(Incidents.class, incidents.getId());
            if (item == null) {
                contains = false;
            }
        } finally {
            mgr.close();
        }
        return contains;
    }

    private static EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return EMF.get().createEntityManager();
    }

}
```

I successfully generated client endpoint libraries and deployed the app to Google App engine.

I thought the key field will be autogenerated.

The problem i am facing now is that the code that inserts the incident fails if i do not set the id field.

Are there errors in my code which caused this problem?

since this field is of Long datatype and must be unique, is there away of adding code to generate it?

I am using an android client app .

Please advise .

Ronald

Answer (score 0):

This part

```
Query query = mgr.createQuery("select from Incidents as Incidents");
```

looks very suspicious for me. It is missing the column list from the `select` clause and I believe you should review the work-flow of all the logistics working with your columns. This might be enough to fix your problem, however, I believe this is where you should start researching your problem.

Comment: Hi. Yes it looks suspecious.. but it is the insert API failing. Retrieving entities works.

Comment: I have also used date.getTime to generate unique long numbers. bad idea?